# Breaking on unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, breakpoints, unrecognized-selector

Is it possible to set a break point on this bit of feedback in the console?  This would make handling this problem so much easier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unrecognized selector is an exception, and you can set a breakpoint on exceptions.

In Xcode 4, go to the breakpoint navigator, click the +, and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint".  Under Exception, choose Objective-C.  Under Break, choose On Throw.  It should look like this when you're done:
[image: http://img.skitch.com/20110909-tp8js5bq2pgkqr5ij89abmm5i8.png]

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I was under the impression I had set this correctly, but I accidentally had Break set to 'On Catch'.

Comment: the + is at the bottom - this is useful to point out since its not intutively obvious