# AdMob crashes the app xcode iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, admob

because the iAd does not work all around the world i decided to try out the AdMob

the problem is that when i start the app there are no errors but when i press play game
the whole app crashes

error ->

> [GADBannerView private]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9159e50 2012-07-30 09:14:12.676 app[1323:c07] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[GADBannerView private]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x9159e50'

code ->

.h

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"
GADBannerView *_AbMob;
@property(nonatomic,retain) GADBannerView *AbMob;
```

.m

```
_AbMob =[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height-195, 320, 50)];

    _AbMob.adUnitID = @"myNumber";
    _AbMob.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_AbMob];



    GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
    r.testing = YES;
```

breakpoint->

```
app`-[GADBannerView adSize] at GADBannerView.m:100:
0x1f5c2:  pushl  %ebp
0x1f5c3:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1f5c5:  pushl  %esi
0x1f5c6:  subl   $20, %esp
0x1f5c9:  calll  0x1f5ce                   ; -[GADBannerView adSize] + 12 at GADBannerView.m:101
0x1f5ce:  popl   %esi
0x1f5cf:  movl   217414(%esi), %eax
0x1f5d5:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1f5d9:  movl   12(%ebp), %eax
0x1f5dc:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1f5df:  calll  0x32022                   ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1f5e4:  movl   217442(%esi), %ecx
0x1f5ea:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x1f5ee:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1f5f1:  calll  0x32022                   ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1f5f6:  movl   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x1f5f9:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1f5fb:  je     0x1f618                   ; -[GADBannerView adSize] + 86 at GADBannerView.m:101
0x1f5fd:  movl   217402(%esi), %edx
0x1f603:  movl   %edx, 8(%esp)
0x1f607:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1f60b:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0x1f60e:  calll  0x32034                   ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend_stret
0x1f613:  addl   $16, %esp
0x1f616:  jmp    0x1f62f                   ; -[GADBannerView adSize] + 109 at GADBannerView.m:101
0x1f618:  movl   $0, 4(%ecx)
0x1f61f:  movl   $0, (%ecx)
0x1f625:  movl   $0, 8(%ecx)
0x1f62c:  addl   $20, %esp
0x1f62f:  popl   %esi
0x1f630:  popl   %ebp
0x1f631:  ret    $4
```

exception at `0x1f5e4:  movl   217442(%esi), %ecx`

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the posted code. Set a breakpoint on the unrecoginzed selector (see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354169/breaking-on-unrecognized-selector)) and post the full stacktrace once the debugger hits the breakpoint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just ran into this problem too. I used the `-all_load` linker flag.

Here is the link you need.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#incorporating

Comment: Voted, you safe my life :D

Comment: Do you mean it must remove `all_load` ? I've removed it, but still the problem

Comment: You need to add the `-all_load` linker flag.