# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, uibutton, nsarray

Ok so I've written an algorithm here that seems to not work. Basically it draws a list of buttons across multiple pages. It's adapted so that 4 buttons will be drawn per page on iPhone 5, and 3 on iPhone 4S and earlier.

But for some reason, in the 'setFrame' method, I get this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The weird thing is that nowhere in the algorithm, or anywhere else in the app does the method `length];` get called.

Please also note that I do no when to use this method, and I also know that `NSArrays` don't have any method `length`.

Here's the algorithm:

```
// creates the chapters
+(void)createChapterInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollview withArray:(NSArray *)array withTarget:(id)target andMethod:(SEL)method
{
    // sets up some initial variable
    int x = 20;
    int y = 40;

    // fills an array with the y values
    int yValues;
    NSMutableArray *yContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (screenHeight == 568) {
        yValues = 4;
    } else {
        yValues = 3;
    }
    for (yValues = yValues; yValues > 0; yValues = yValues - 1) {
        [yContainer addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", y]];
        y = y + 70;
    }

    // creates the buttons using the number of pages
    int numOfpages = [self numOfPagesFromArray:array];
    int numofPagesLeft = [self numOfPagesFromArray:array];
    int numOfButtonsLeft = [array count];
    int currentButton = 0;

    if (numofPagesLeft == 0) {

    } else {
        for (numofPagesLeft = numofPagesLeft; numofPagesLeft >= 0; numofPagesLeft = numofPagesLeft - 1) {
            for (id object in yContainer) {
                if (numOfButtonsLeft > 0) {
                    UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    [newButton setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:currentButton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [newButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                    [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, [object floatValue], 280, 50)];
                    [newButton setTag:(currentButton+1)];
                    [newButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
                    [newButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
                    [newButton addTarget:target action:method forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [scrollview addSubview:newButton];
                    numOfButtonsLeft = numOfButtonsLeft - 1;
                    currentButton ++;
                }
            }
            x = x + 320;
        }
    }

    // checks if any buttons were actually created
    if (numOfpages == 0) {
        // tells the user that no content has been downloaded
        UILabel *errorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 216)];
        [errorLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [errorLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [errorLabel setNumberOfLines:10];
        [errorLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
        [errorLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [errorLabel setText:@"Oops!\n\nLooks like no readable content has been downloaded!\n\nThe content will be automatically downloaded right now!"];
        [scrollview addSubview:errorLabel];
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you show us the numOfPagesFromArray method?

Comment: Where is `screenheight` defined?

Comment: Run it under the Zombies instrument.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to the Breakpoints navigator, and add exception breakpoint. Simple description how to do it is [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354169/breaking-on-unrecognized-selector)

Once you have this, you should see exactly which line of code causes the exception.