# Printing address book to console with NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, abaddressbook, nslog

I'm using this in my `viewWillAppear:` to print all my contacts names and numbers to my console.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
            if (granted) {
                // First time access has been granted, add all the user's contacts to array.

                contactsObjects = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef));
            } else {
                // User denied access.
                // Display an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add all the user's contacts to array.

        contactsObjects = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef));
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", contactsObjects);
}
```

and here's the output

[image]

With this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ec2190'***
```

What's the problem?

**EDIT** problem found with breakpoint for Exception on throw:
FULL .m:

```
@synthesize inviteTableSearchBar;

@synthesize contactsObjects;
@synthesize facebookObjects;
@synthesize twitterObjects;
@synthesize searchResults;

//lazy instantiations <below>-------
- (NSArray *)contactsObjects
{
    if(!contactsObjects)
    {
        contactsObjects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    }

    return contactsObjects;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)searchResults
{
    if(!searchResults)
    {
        searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return searchResults;
}
//lazy instantiations <above>-------

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
            if (granted) {
                // First time access has been granted, add all the user's contacts to array.

                contactsObjects = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef));
            } else {
                // User denied access.
                // Display an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add all the user's contacts to array.

        contactsObjects = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef));
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user that they must allow access to proceed to the "invites" page.
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", contactsObjects);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //CUSTOM APPEARANCE <below>

    //set in order to actually change the search bar's UIColor.
    [self.inviteTableSearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.inviteTableSearchBar setTranslucent:YES];

    self.inviteTableSearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#333333"];
    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];

    //Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations; YES to clear tableView when the tableViewController recieves `viewWillAppear:`
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;

    //Fill array
    //[self.contactsObjects addObject:@"Examples<below>"];
    //[self.contactsObjects addObject:@"John"];
    //[self.contactsObjects addObject:@"Sanford"];
    //[self.contactsObjects addObject:@"Sally"];
    //[self.contactsObjects addObject:@"Susan B. Anthony"];

    // Hide the search bar until user scrolls up
    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + inviteTableSearchBar.bounds.size.height;
    self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.contactsObjects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //configure the cells
    cell.textLabel.text = self.contactsObjects[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Problem is on `cell.textLabel.text = self.contactsObjects[indexPath.row];` underneath the `//configure the cells`. in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: What line is crashing?

Comment: sorry man I'm not sure were that value is. If this were java I could but I don't know where that is on Xcode (full debugger report is now listed)

Comment: Wow this should not be that difficult. I've spent all day just trying to figure out how to print my contacts to my console just to make sure that I've actually grabbed them.

Comment: what you want to show in the table Phone Number or user name?

Comment: Username. I just need the username to show in the table. Or I guess it'll be their actual name? Since this is just pulled from my contacts list on *my* iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

 id p=[contactsObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *fName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
      NSString *lName=(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName),CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)]
```

Comment: Genius! It works, buttt.. it's printing the same contact over in every cell.. and I'm trying to figure out why right now...

Comment: I think it's the objectAtIndex:0. Also I'd like to include the last names too

Comment: Yeah.. if I change it to `objectAtIndex:1]` it prints out a different name, and prints that name for every cell in the tableView.

Comment: indexpath.row use this

Comment: NICE. it worked. Dude your good lol. One last question.. would you happen to know how to also include last names? like, right after first names?

Comment: use of undeclared identifier `'allNames'`. what is that variable? An NSObject?

Comment: HAHA I figured that last one out at the same time

Comment: sorry check it out.. that was my array you should replace your array noyhing else

Comment: dude thank you soooo much. You just saved me like 4 hours of restless internet surfing.

Comment: Hey one last question. Any easy way to get the "(null)" names to not show? Like I have some contacts that are missing last names, or first I'm not really sure, but it actually shows `(null)` for the people who don't have both names listed

Comment: +1+1 Unbelievable dude. You are the best stack answerer I've ever run across. Props.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you've attempted to ask the object at address 0x175c4b10 for its length, but it is not an object that responds to the method `length`. The error is probably not in the code you've posted, since you do not make any calls to the `length` method there. It could be that you're calling `length` somewhere else (search your code for where), or it could be that you're calling a method which eventually calls `length`, but you're passing it an invalid parameters.

Comment: Is there a way that I can tell which class this instance is coming from?

Comment: Actually that's a stupid question because I know what page it crashes on

Comment: You can add a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions. To do this, open the breakpoints pane, click the "+" button, and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint…". By default it should stop on C++ and Objective-C exceptions (I think). That should cause your program to stop in the debugger as soon as it hits the problem line.

Comment: Ahh, and so the breakpoint will then appear at the source? sorry I've never even used breakpoints..

Comment: you're right. I found out how to use the breakpoints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354169/breaking-on-unrecognized-selector